# A "nativelog" application shows up in my Desktop

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Question, whenever I start up my Minecraft a notepad application appears on my desktop called "nativelog", how do I remove that from ever popping up? Thanks.

Comment: someone on Minecraft Forums had the same problem, check it out:  http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support/2334380-minecraft-files-keep-generating-on-my-desktop

Comment: I just had the same issue on my laptop, and it looks like this is not a duplicate after all. I have a simple solution for it as well.